# how do i fix the error message i received when running bundle install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode, rvm, homebrew

I am new to ruby and rails. I just installed Xcode, homebrew, rvm, a new version of ruby, and a new version of rails. I started a dummy project. I ran `rails new MySite` and `bundle install`. When I ran bundle install I got the following error:

```
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory.
```

Did I do something wrong on the installation? How do I fix it? I have not tried anything to fix the problem because I do not know where to start.

Comment: Your question will be much easier to read (and answer) if you use the code formatting (backticks or indent 4 spaces), and break up the specific commands or error messages into separate paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

Rails will run `bundle install` by default when you create using `rails new MySite`.

In any case the reason why it did not work is most likely because you weren't in the directory containing the `Gemfile`, just `cd MySite` and then run `bundle install`

Comment: @user6437739 you should consider accepting the answer, see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

First use the command:

```
bundle init
```

This will set up a new `./Gemfile` in the current directory.

- documentation: http://bundler.io/v1.12/bundle_init.html
- code: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/dfdeb0f89e7e88fcdfd001da089f09af3a77d2b4/lib/bundler/cli/init.rb

---

Also see this guide about using Bundler with Rails: **http://bundler.io/rails3.html**. The guide is for Rails 3, but it should work for Rails 4 too.